# Unity Interception - unwanted recursion

Tags: c#, unity-container

I've tried implementing Unity's interception but I'm having a weird problem where invoking the getNext delegate causes some unwanted recursion.

In the attached screenshot you can see the stack trace during some debugging. In this case I'm breaking on the call:

```
  var methodReturn = getNext()(input, getNext);
```

[image: Callstack]

notice now the call has now happened 5 times. What's interesting about this problem is the number of times it repeats is dependent on where in my architecture the call originates. Here the first call for interception occurred as SetupSession, which is pretty high up in my call stack and this repeats about 8 times. When I get lower, down towards my data layer, it only happens once (which is correct).

I'm following the guides here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466(v=pandp.30).aspx

using the .AddNewExtension() and I've got a decorator around the standard UnityContainer which, when calling RegisterType() adding the two extra injections for every registration:

```
  new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(),
  new InterceptionBehavior<NLoggerInterceptor>()
```

I'm pretty lost here so any ideas are welcome!

Thanks

Comment: That's very weird, can you please post the unity container setup, unity registertype code and the interceptor code?

Comment: I actually just found the issue, it was a case where these interfaces taht get duplicated interceptors were getting registered more than once. Normally that isn't an issue except the interceptors were also stacking.

So, valuable lesson: injections stack if you register multiple times.

Comment: @MatthewBonig, I think it would be useful to post your comment as an answer and accept it (after the 48 hour time limit expires).